# How can I change the name property of the objects in my mutable array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sprite-kit

I have a mutable array called removeRedCirclesArray.  Each object in the array is an SKShapeNode with a name property.  I'd simply like to run through each object in the array and change the object's name property to "bigRedCircle".  The code below is how I think it would work but it creates this Xcode error: "@lvalue $T7 is not identical to String!"

```
for var x = 0; x <= removeRedCirclesArray.count - 1; x++ {
        removeRedCirclesArray[x].name = "bigRedCircle"
        }
```

What is the correct way to accomplish this seemingly simple task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  In order to access the name property, I have to tell xCode what type of object is in my array by doing the following:

```
(removeRedCirclesArray.objectAtIndex(x) as SKShapeNode).name = bigRedCircle
```

Answer (score 0):

SKNode.name is a String Optional
var name: String?

Are you attempting to access the value without unwrapping it somewhere else? It does not appear to be in this code.

See
https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/name

Comment: How would I go about unwrapping it?

Comment: @Alan_s there's the trick! You didn't mention the array was an NSArray and not Swift array :) Glad you figured it out.